# What is the difference between conform and adapt?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between "conform" and "adapt"?

Could you clarify the words' meaning and usage with examples?

First, let's look at the Cambridge dictionary's definition:

> **conform**
>
> to behave according to the usual standards of behavior that
> are expected by a group or society

> **adapt**
>
> to change, or to change something, to suit different conditions
> or uses

What I understand from the difference between these words is that adapting is changing our behavior/thought/attitude to suit a new environment (maybe permanent change), but conforming is just following the new environment's rules.

Comment: Please edit your question to describe the research you have done in your efforts to answer  it by yourself. [See: Details, Please.](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)

Answer (score 1):

*Conform*, as your dictionary says, usually means to follow the standards of behaviour that are accepted as normal in the society in which you live. An example of *not* conforming would be to wear casual clothes to work when everyone else wears formal business attire.

To *adapt* is to change yourself or your behaviour, for instance a plant or animal adapting to the changing climate. If you are used to dressing smartly for work and you get a new job with a firm where employees dress casually, you need to *adapt* your style of dress in order to *conform* with your new colleagues!